# String not printing as expected

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, tcpclient

Could you please explain why the Output window does not print the "xxxxx" part of the string? 
Looks like I'm missing some basic understanding about something...?

I'm sending string messages over TcpClient, and when building the strings, I don't add any special characters on the sender side, and neither on the receiver side. Is this part of the problem?

http://i56.tinypic.com/9lg7pi.png

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

I'm building my strings at the sender side like this:

```
Private Sub SendData(ByVal stringArray As String())
    SendData(GetMessageString(stringArray))
End Sub

Public Function GetMessageString(ByVal array As String()) As String
    Dim str As String = ""
    For i = 0 To array.Length - 1
        str = str & array(i)
        If i < array.Length - 1 Then
            str = str & "|"
        End If
    Next
    Return str
End Function
```

And on receiving side, the variable is built:

```
     client.GetStream.BeginRead(readBodyBuffer, 0, MESSAGE_BODY_LENGTH, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf ReadBody), Nothing)

    ...

Private Sub ReadBody(ByVal aread As IAsyncResult)

      BytesRead = client.GetStream.EndRead(aread)

    ...

          ' Read (add) into buffer
      messagePart = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBodyBuffer)
      messagePart = messagePart & "xxxxx"
```

---

**EDIT 3**

My simple mistake was wrong use of Redim of the byte array: 
(parameter 10 gives 11 elements)

Wrong:

```
 ReDim readBodyBuffer(MESSAGE_BODY_LENGTH)
```

Correct:

```
 ReDim readBodyBuffer(MESSAGE_BODY_LENGTH - 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is somehow related to non-printable characters. For example this C# code:

```
string message = "Hello\0 Hello2";
Debug.Print(message);
```

Here I have a string with null character at the end. In debug visualizer it displays in the same way as I created this string - `"Hello\0 Hello2"`. But in output window it doesn't display `\0` and even truncates `Hello 2`. So I think it relates to your issue though I couldn't reproduce it completely. Check your `messagePart.Length`.

**UPDATE:** Ok, so after going through all these comments here and in another answer I think that the issue is caused by incorrect usage of `readBodyBuffer`. It depends on how you allocate this buffer, but I expect that you're simply creating a new byte array with fixed (11) length. Then you're ignoring the number of bytes which were actually received (10) and converting string from that array using ASCII encoding. The fact that `BytesRead` less than allocated buffer size causes the fact that last byte in array is zero. You should use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString` method which accepts `length` argument so you won't receive `\0` in result string:

```
messagePart = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBodyBuffer, 0, ReadBytes)
```

Comment: Hmm.. Yes, the messagePart length is 16, which is one character more than I would expect. Though I don't know where this is added? I edited with some details on how the strings are handled above.

Comment: @bretddog, can you dump the content of `readBodyBuffer`? I suspect the problem is in `10` index.

Comment: @Snowbear:  Sorry what you mean "dump the content"?  The string is  "CONNECTED|"

Comment: @bretddog, i mean you should print content of `readBodyBuffer` array. It should be smth like `[67, 79, ...`

Comment: I see. It prints: 67
79
78
78
69
67
84
69
68
124
0

Comment: So readBodyBuffer.Length = 11, while the variable BytesRead = 10

Comment: Ah.. Thanks! :) I see now my mistake. I send the message length at the start of each message to allow for dynamic message lengths, like this:   "000010CONNECTED|"  But my mistake is with the Redim: I thought Redim readBuffer(10) gives 10 elements (0-9), but it gives 11 (0-10).    ehm.. blush

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Snowbear.

Could you print char code of the white space in your message? It should be 32 for the space.

```
Debug.Print(AscW(messagePart(10)))
```

Comment: Not sure what this means, but if I print:   Debug.Print(AscW(messagePart))  it outputs 67    ?

Comment: @bretddog - 67 is ascii code of `C` char which is first character in your string, you need to print ascii code for `10` index in `messagePart`

Comment: This zero is the problem when using Debug.Print function. To work around the issue you can remove or replace this zero before passing to the function. Like this: message.Replace(ChrW(0), " ")

Comment: I see.. But why is the zero there in the first place? And should I remove it from the end of each received string, when building a message from multiple parts?

Comment: Please don’t consider the work around as a good solution. Probably, the zero char at the end of message could rise issues in other parts of the system as well. It is a good time to summarize all the details and make a decision.